# How to connect to MariaDB using C# MySqlClient

Tags: c#, mysql, mariadb

I have installed MariaDB in my own NAS drive, and created a database using phpMyAdmin. But I am having problem connecting to the database using C#.

Connection String :

```
server=localhost:/run/mysqld/mysqld10.sock;port=3307;database=dbName;uid=user;password=pwd;
```

C# Code :

```
connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["qilinConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
connection.Open();
```

Error Message :

> [SocketException (0x2af9): No such host is known]

Any ideas on how to connect to the database? Thank you in advance

Comment: I think the default port is 3306. have you changed it?

Comment: @parthivrshah when I installed MariaDB 10 in NAS, it is defaulted to port 3307

Comment: erver=localhost:3307/run/mysqld/mysqld10.sock;database=dbName;uid=user;password=pwd;    try this

Comment: still getting the same error :(

Comment: Are you running the C# program on the NAS?

Comment: No, I am doing the C# code in my laptop

Comment: Then you should forget localhost. It is relative and means the computer the application is running on. You need the IP address or hostname of the NAS

Comment: I tried change the localhost to the IP Address on the NAS, but still getting the same error

Comment: telnet 127.0.0.1 3307 can you please try this?

Comment: have you add `using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;`?

Comment: did you change the connection string to "server=<ip address of nas>;port=3307;database=dbName;uid=user;password=pwd;" ? Please post it. The error "No such host is known" should be gone

Comment: I changed the connection string to server=<ip address>/run/mysqld/mysqld10.sock;port=3307;database=dbName;uid=user;password=pwd;   But the error still there

Comment: @Prochu1991 yes

Comment: @lanthe Please remove the :/run/mysqld/mysqld10.sock from the connection string. Only the IP address (or network name) is valid for server value